# Indentation of li items in ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to show list items with some text. And I want every single item to be indented 10-20px to the right from the previous one. I don't have much experience with css.

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos"
    ng-class="{'selectedToDo': (todo.id == selectedToDo)}">
    {{todo.toDoText}}
</li>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikolakoco/Y6vNN/2/) with my code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may use [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle) to solve your problem:

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos"
        ng-class="{'selectedToDo': (todo.id == selectedToDo)}" 
        ng-style="{'margin-left': 10*$index+'px'}">

     {{todo.toDoText}}
</li>
```

`$index` is a varibale that will be set by `ng-repeat`. You may use this to calculate your style.

Answer (score 3):

Change your template with following::

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos"
            ng-class="{'selectedToDo': (todo.id == selectedToDo)}" style="text-indent: {{$index * 10}}px">
            {{todo.toDoText}} 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```